# Representing functions as trees

Tags: function, haskell, tree

I'm doing a past Function Programming exam paper and have this question:

> Here are two ways of writing essentially the same expression:
>
> f (g(x,y),z,h(t))
>
> f (g x y) z (h t)
>
> (a) Illustrate the different structures of the two expressions by drawing them as two different kinds of tree.
>
> (b) Define Haskell data types Bush a and Tree a to capture the two different structures.

I'm kind of stuck because I've never done any thing like this in my course. It's pretty obvious from a later part that the first expression should be represented by `Tree a` and the second by `Bush a`, but I don't really know where to go from here. I guessed something like:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a)
data Bush a = Node a [Bush a]
```

But I don't think the Binary tree type is the right one to use. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the first expression is represented by `Bush` and the second by `Tree`.

In Haskell, `g x y` means that `g x` is applied to `y`; in C, `g(x, y)` means that `g` is applied to a collection of arguments — `{x, y}`. Therefore, in C:

```
f(g(x,y),z,h(t)) = Bush f [Bush g [Bush x [], Bush y []], Bush z [], Bush h [Bush t []]]

  f
  +--g
  |  +--x
  |  +--y
  |
  +--z
  |
  +--h
     +--t
```

And in Haskell:

```
f (g x y) z (h t) = App (App (App f (App (App g x) y)) z) (App h t)

         +
        / \
       /  /\
      +  h  t  
     / \
    /\  z
   f  +
     / \
    /\  y
   g  x
```

Comment: Really? In part (c) the question asks to me to create a function `curry :: Bush a -> Tree a` Surely the second one is the uncurried expression and therefore must be `Bush a`?

Comment: Look at the signature of `curry`: `((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c`. It makes a ”Haskell” function out of “C” one — that is, from Bush to Tree.

Comment: Ah right. So my definitions given in my response to the first reply should be the other way around?

Comment: The definitions are `data Bush a = Leaf a | Node a [Bush a]` and `data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a)` — they were almost right in your original post.